Write a kafka consumer in Nodejs
I'm using kafkajs library and below is my consumer code.
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');

// Create a Kafka consumer
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-kafka-consumer',
  brokers: ['broker-address:9092'],
  ssl: true,
  sasl: {
     mechanism: 'plain',
     username: 'api-key',
     password: 'api-secret'

}
});
const consumer = kafka.consumer({ groupId: 'test-group' }); // Specify your consumer group ID

// Function to consume messages from Kafka topic
const consumeMessages = async () => {
  try {
    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'test topic' }); 
    await consumer.run({
      eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
        console.log({
          topic,
          partition,
          offset: message.offset,
          value: message.value.toString()
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error consuming messages:', error);
  }
};

consumeMessages();

but when I try to run the consumer it gives bellow error.
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-04-19T11:10:41.217Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: read ECONNRESET","broker":"broker-address:9092","clientId":"my-kafka-consumer","stack":"Error: read ECONNRESET\n    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-04-19T11:10:41.221Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Co
nnection error: read ECONNRESET","retryCount":0,"retryTime":262}

I can consume from this same topic with a spring kafka consumer application and I'm giving below parameters in the properties file in that application to connect to the cluster.
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: server-url:9092
    properties:
      security.protocol: SASL_SSL
      basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
      sasl:
        mechanism: PLAIN
        jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='${CLUSTER_API_KEY}' password='${CLUSTER_API_SECRET}';
      schema.registry:
        url: <schema url>
        basic.auth.user.info: ${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KEY}:${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SECRET}
      auto.register.schemas: false

In Nodejs, how to configure these properties in the consumer to properly to connect to the topic?

Have you seen the docs on SASL PLAIN configuration? https://kafka.js.org/docs/configuration#sasl

@OneCricketeer even though I added this below code snippet it still fails to connect to the bootstrap server. " ssl: true,
sasl: {
mechanism: 'plain',
username: 'api key',
password: 'api secret'
},  "

Maybe also need a connection timeout? https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/611#issuecomment-610841223

@OneCricketeer I just added that timeout to be 3000. Now it gives, {"message":"[Connection] Response GroupCoordinator(key: 10, version: 2)","broker":"broker-url:9092","clientId":"my-kafka-consumer","error":"Not authorized to access group: Group authorization failed","correlationId":2,"size":
49}    Also I notice that the broker url is a bit different in the error msg.

Does your cluster only allow you to use specific group ids and test-group isn't defined / allowed?

@OneCricketeer yes you were right. I changed the group id to a allowed one. But now it is giving "logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Consumer] Crash: KafkaJSProtocolError: The group member's supported protocols are inc
ompatible with those of existing members","groupId":"cg-mm","stack":"KafkaJSProtocolError: The group member's supported protocols are incompatible with those of existing members\n

I've not seen that before, but sounds like there are other consumers actively using that group. Should kafkajs be trying to read the same messages as them? Or use a unique group?

If there is another consumer with the same group-id then is it expect to have this error? I'm not very familiar with kafka logics. Apologies for my basic questions @OneCricketeer

If you have Java/Spring apps in the same consumer group as KafkaJS, they might conflict. https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/463#issuecomment-520498511

@OneCricketeer Thanks this would be the case for the above error as we are having another Java consumer. But I need a one more clarification. I have both cluster API key/secret and Schema registry API key/secret for a specific env. I can consume from the topic only with the cluster API key/secret. Shouldn't I use the schema API key/secret? Is it enough to use cluster creds to connect?

To connect, yes. To deserialize the data, no. You'll need another library and not use toString on the value https://kafkajs.github.io/confluent-schema-registry/docs/usage#basic-auth

@OneCricketeer now I can consume the events. But when I try to decode the consumed message it gives below error "stack: Error: truncated buffer\n    at Type.fromBuffer" The code snippet is, "const avroEncodedMessage = Buffer.from(message.value, 'binary');
const decodedMessage = schema.fromBuffer(avroEncodedMessage);" do you have an idea why this issue comes. I'm using a Java producer and NodeJs consumer

The linked library uses await registry.decode function, not schema.fromBuffer. Native avro Javascript library doesn't know how to parse the Schema Registry binary format
